# Changing a ListBox selection changes other ListBox's selection. What's going on?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I've got a Windows Forms application with two ListBox controls on the same form.
They both have their SelectionMode set to 'MultiExtended'.

When I change the selection of one the selection of the other changes.

Now I thought I'd done something stupid with my SelectedIndexChanged handlers so I removed them and re-wrote them from scratch, and got the problem.

So I created a brand new WinForms app and dragged two ListBoxes onto the forms surface.

In the constructor I populated them both with the following.

```
List<Thing> data = new List<Thing>();

for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
        Thing temp = new Thing();
        temp.Letters = "abc " + i.ToString();
        temp.Id = i;
        data.Add(temp);
}

listBox1.DataSource = data;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Letters";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";


List<Thing> data2 = new List<Thing>();

for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
    Thing temp = new Thing();
    temp.Letters = "abc " + i.ToString();
    temp.Id = i;
    data2.Add(temp);
}

listBox2.DataSource = data2;
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Letters";
listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
```

And then I built and ran the app.

Started selecting some values to see if the symptoms were present.
And they were!

This is literally all the code I added to the form,I had not added any event handlers, I have tried it with the SelectionMode set to 'One' and 'MultiExtended'.

Can anyone give me a clue as to why this is happening.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't the *list* that stores the current position - it is the `CurrencyManager`. Any controls (with the same `BindingContext`) with the *same reference* as a `DataSource` will share a `CurrencyManager`. By using different list instances you get different `CurrencyManager` instances, and thus separate position.

You could achieve the same simply by using `.ToList()`, or creating a new `List<T>` with the same contents (as per your original post), or by assigning a new `BindingContext` to one of the controls:

```
control.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your two controls are sharing a CurrencyManager.  I'm not sure exactly why.
As a workaround, you could try just populating your listboxes with simple strings.  Or you may want to try creating separate instances of the BindingSource component, and bind to those.

Comment: Any tips on how to get them to use different ones?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how they are sharing one.  I tried a simple example like Shaun Bowe, and the listbox selection appears independent.  Can you reproduce the problem from a clean solution?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same when I used the same datasource on both listboxes, but creating two equal datasources solved the problem for me.  I can see nothing wrong with your code.  Anything particular with the Thing class ?  Or does it just contain the two members Letters and Id ?

Comment: Yes, Just the two members.

A really simple class purely for my example.

Answer (score 1):

And more...

I finally got ot the bottom of it.

I was binding the two ListBoxes to the same List. by changing the code to

```
theListBox.DataSource = _contacts.Take(_contacts.Count).ToList();
```

the issue was curcumvented.

It seems that the reference to the List that it stored also caries any binding or selection information over to the other ListBox.

be careful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new win forms app with two list boxes on it. They behave as I would expect. Can you post the complete code? Here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private class Thing
{
  public String Letters { get; set; }
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<Thing> data = new List<Thing>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    Thing temp = new Thing();
    temp.Letters = "abc " + i.ToString();
    temp.Id = i;
    data.Add(temp);
  }

  listBox1.DataSource = data;
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Letters";
  listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";


  List<Thing> data2 = new List<Thing>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    Thing temp = new Thing();
    temp.Letters = "abc " + i.ToString();
    temp.Id = i;
    data2.Add(temp);
  }

  listBox2.DataSource = data2;
  listBox2.DisplayMember = "Letters";
  listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate this behavior on my own machine and was unable to do so running just the code your provided.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected.

In another instance of VS in a brand new solution, this works as expected.

God only know's what i've done to make it do what it's doing